# Add line to table when split

Tags: html, itext

I have a table format in HTML for printing.When the table is loaded with larger data the table will get split and aligned in two pages.The problem is ,due to split in the table it will loss the bottom line and upper line(Please refer Image).I am using ITextSharp to convert HTML to Pdf  for printing.When data is less, The table will align on one page and looks fine.How Can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]